# Run a program (with user interface) when a windows service crashes a thrird time

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-services

I have build a WPF application and several windows services it relies on.
In order for the program to work correctly I need to make sure all of my services are running. I've set up following recovery:

- 1st failure: Restart Service
- 2nd failure: Restart Service
- 3rd failure: Run a program -> With the path to the executable of my custom made application 'Service Crash Report' (This is an other WPF application that just has a mainwindow with a text saying the service has crashed and the user might have to look into what's going on).

When I test this setup and make my service crash (using the task manager), step 1 & 2 work as expected (The service restarts). But when I make my service crash a third time, I can see my executable is run (in the taskmanager the process is started) but I don't see my UI showing up.

Is there a way I can make sure the service recovery process shows my UI?
Or is it not possible to inform the user that my service has crashed?

Edit:

I have allready tried turning on 'Allow service to interact with the desktop', and as a result I get my message opened in the backgound. I do get informed about it like this:

http://snag.gy/aQIYS.jpg (I added this url because i can't post images yet..)

Offcourse this is not what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Have you set the service property 'Allow service to interact with the desktop'? I think MS are removing this ability starting in Windows 8 so you might want to think again.

Comment: Here's an article on interactive services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: As you can see I edited my question, showing what happens if I turn on that property. As for Windows 8 support I don't have to worry about that, the application only supports Windows 7.